# How do I wait for an async function to complete within a condition?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

I have an IF condition that has asynchronous code within it. I want to wait for the process within the condition to complete before proceeding with other code execution. How can this be achieved? My code is as below:

```
  List<String> imageURLs = [];
  if (images.length > 0) {
    images.forEach((element) async  {
      String imageURL = await savePostImage(element);
      imageURLs.add(imageURL);
    });
  } //This should complete
  data.addAll({'images': imageURLs}); /For this to be executed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Future.forEach`

```
await Future.forEach(images, (element) {
  // Your logic ...
});
```

Comment: Or a normal `for` loop.